# least squares equation in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode

How I can write this equation in LaTeX,[image] which represents the least squares method?

Comment: Welcome! What have you got so far?

Comment: My (perhaps shaky) understanding is that you don't ever use the `\times` symbol to represent matrix multiplication, because it could be ambiguous with the cross product.

Comment: are the delimiters of the part before the equals sign "celiling"s, or regular brackets?  (they look to be like `\lceil` and `\rceil`, but i could be mistaken.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{amsart}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
 y_1 \\ \vdots \\ y_{34} 
 \end{bmatrix}
 =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  -y_0 && u & u\\
  \vdots && \vdots & \vdots \\
  -y_{33} && u & u
  \end{pmatrix}
  \times
  \begin{pmatrix}
  a \\ b_0 \\ b_1
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT:

If you want the type of brackets that Barbara Beeton think you might want, then the following would work.

```
\documentclass{amsart}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\left\lceil
\begin{array}{c}
 y_1 \\ \vdots \\ y_{34} 
 \end{array}
 \right\rceil
 =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  -y_0 && u & u\\
  \vdots && \vdots & \vdots \\
  -y_{33} && u & u
  \end{pmatrix}
  \times
  \begin{pmatrix}
  a \\ b_0 \\ b_1
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: very big thanx that work, I tired of trying  :(

Comment: Feel free to accept it ;)

Comment: I had forced to wait 8 minuts :D

Comment: @JPi -- please note the question i asked in a comment above, about the delimiters for the first element of the equation.

Comment: thanks @barbarabeeton.  That hadn't occurred to me.  I am a bit puzzled by the use of different types of delimiters on the left and right hand sides regardless.

Comment: Upvoted, but why `gather` for a single equation? Please, remove it and favor `equation` in this case.

Comment: Done.   I've gotten into a habit of using `gather` no matter where.  Is there any advantage of using `equation` instead of `gather` when using `amsmath` other than that gather is primarily intended for multi-equation situations?  I've seen no typographical reason for preferring one over the other.